# What tools or libraries are there for decompiling python and exploring bytecode?

Tags: python, decompiling

Lets say I have:

```
>>> def test(a):    
>>>    print a
```

Now, I want to explore see how test looks like in its compiled form.

```
>>> test.func_code.co_code
'|\x00\x00GHd\x00\x00S'
```

I can get the disassembled form using the **dis** module:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 PRINT_ITEM
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Is there an opensource and maintained decompiler I could use to turn the bytecode back into readable python code?

**update: thanks for suggesting decompile, but it's outdated (python2.3) and no one maintains it anymore. Is there anything for python2.5 or later?**

Answer (score 6):

**UnPyc**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unpyc/

It is a maintained fork of the old decompyle updated to work with 2.5 and 2.6.

Comment: From the project's readme.txt: "D  - decompile (not implemented yet)". So no, this is a poor substitute for decompyle.

Answer (score 5):

get uncompyle2 from github! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is also now [uncompyle6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=uncompyle6&:action=display) and the more narrow [decompyle3](https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3) (for Python 3.7 and 3.8 and is not packaged). Both of these are written in Python. Also there is [pycdc](https://github.com/zrax/pycdc) written in C++.

These handle several versions of Python bytecode starting from Python 1 and going to Python 3 versions, except where noted above.

Another thing you might consider is a bytecode interpreter which allows you to trace and/or step bytecode instructions.

For this there is [x-python](https://pypi.org/project/x-python/) for the interpreter and [trepanxpy](https://pypi.org/project/trepanxpy/) the gdb-like debugger for that. See the links for the Python bytecode versions that are interpreted and for which Python versions are needed to run the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

[decompyle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/decompyle/)

> Decompyle is a python disassembler and
>   decompiler which converts Python
>   byte-code (.pyc or .pyo) back into
>   equivalent Python source. Verification
>   of the produced code (re-compiled) is
>   avaliable as well.

Comment: Yes. For python 2.3, anything usable with Python 2.5+?

Answer (score 2):

Uncompyle2 worked for me with Python 2.7.

https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2

Quick how to use uncompyle2 , Install it and then

```
>>>import uncompyle2
>>> with open("decompiled.py","wb") as f:
...   uncompyle2.uncompyle_file("compiled.pyc",f)
```

It will generate source code back in decompile.py

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what DevC wrote:

1. Uncompyle2 works with Python 2.7
2. with Uncompyle2, you can also un-compile from the command line:

   $ uncompyle2 compiled.pyc >> source.uncompyle2.py
3. to install Uncompyle2, do

   $ git clone https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2

   $ cd uncompyle2

   $ sudo ./setup.py install