# Python application decompiler

Tags: python, decompiling

I have a website that offers files to people; this site is related to a SAT decoder based on Linux. Some people developed "plugins" written in Python that access my site and get those files directly from the decoder without visiting the site. I know I could block them by using JavaScript methods on the website but I would like to know what this plugin does first.  The files of those plugins are a series of `pyo` files which, from what I understood, are compiled Python scripts.

Is there a way I can get the source of those files or at least see what they "call"?

I only found non-working or not free services. I mean there must be a way; people crack almost every software made by major software houses and I can't "get" what a Python script does?

Comment: You may want to properly rephrase the title of your question. And use the search function before asking.

Comment: Just to clarify, you already have access to the plugins but don't know what they do (besides downloading your files)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exploring and decompiling python bytecode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149513/exploring-and-decompiling-python-bytecode)

Answer (score 1):

[Exploring and decompiling python bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149513/exploring-and-decompiling-python-bytecode)

Comment: I tried decompyle I wasn't able to install it in ubuntu 10.04, online services don't work with the files I have :(