# python: how to get the source from a code object?

Tags: python, decompiling

let's suppose we have a python string(not a file,a string,no files)

```
TheString = "k=abs(x)+y"
```

ok? Now we compile the string into a piece of python bytecode

```
Binary = compile( TheString , "<string>" , "exec" )
```

now the problem: how can i get from Binary , supposing i don't know TheString , a string that represents the original string object?

shortly: what is the function that is opposite to compile() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149513/exploring-and-decompiling-python-bytecode

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without the source code, you can only approximate the code. You can *disassemble* the compiled bytecode with the [`dis` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html), then reconstruct the source code as an approximation:

```
>>> import dis
>>> TheString = "k=abs(x)+y"
>>> Binary = compile( TheString , "<string>" , "exec" )
>>> dis.dis(Binary)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (abs)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (x)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 LOAD_NAME                2 (y)
             12 BINARY_ADD          
             13 STORE_NAME               3 (k)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

From the disassembly we can see there was 1 line, where a function named `abs()` is being called with one argument named `x`. The result is added to another name `y`, and the result is stored in `k`.

Projects like [`uncompile6`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncompyle6) (building [on top of the work of many others](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/blob/master/HISTORY.md)) do just that; decompile the python bytecode and reconstruct Python code from that.

Comment: `unpyc` and `uncompyle2` look super old (7 years, 9 years) respectively. Do you know if there's anything more... modern? Which also supports Python3? -- Nevermind.. found it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncompyle6

Comment: @exhuma: this answer is pretty old too, at 5 years and counting ;-) Yes, the various decompilation packages have been morphing and changing over the years, I'll update.

Comment: @exhuma - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file/14808336#14808336) mentions Uncompyle6: