# How to print the body of imported method or function in python?

Tags: python, python-import

I am currently using online python interpreter.
The problem is here, there are some pre-loaded variables or functions which do not appear on the interactive editor, just there is an instruction which informs their name and their final output.
*The question here is, how to find out the structure of the functions or in other words how to print their scopes?*


For instance, instruction indicates the name of a function is ***get_mse()*** and It operates Mean Squared Error and also gets three arguments, then It is ready to use but I want to know what It consists of.

Note: These imported functions are not built-in and certainly manipulated and imported from other python files which are not available from the source.

Comment: use locals() and globals() dict to get value within scope ; if u want the source use inspect method

Comment: Am I understanding correctly you want to get the source of an imported function... or...?

Comment: If you're looking for the source code, it is unlikely you'll be able to get it. [See this for some methods to try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function).

Comment: @JonClements Yes, That is

Comment: @Norrius, I had seen this question but if you considered, this method worked when the function is accessible from the source.

Comment: @JonClements, I have seen this question before asking here but there are a little bit differences. In that question, the top rated answer mentioned the condition is true when 'the function is from a source file available on the filesystem'.

Comment: you would need the `get_mse.__code__` object and then you could take an approach like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15432550/3220135). Getting that code object onto an interpreter that you can import `dis` or `uncompyle2` on however isn't going to be terribly straightforward. I guess the first thing to try is importing `dis` on the interpreter you have..

Comment: @JoyeBright then you need to [edit] your question to include all the bits you've tried and why they don't work for you. Heck - an online interpreter could even inject things into its own builtins to do all sorts of things - so there's possibly not even really any code anyway...