# Lost important .py file (overwritten as 0byte file), but the old version still loaded in ipython as module -- can it be retrieved?

Tags: python, linux, vim, ipython, recovery

While managing several different screen sessions with vim open in many of them, in the process of trying to "organize" my sessions I somehow managed to overwrite a very important .py script with a 0Byte file.

However, I have an ipython instance open that, when running that same .py file as a module, still remembers the code that used to be there!

So did I just learn a hard lesson about backups (my last one was done by vim about a week ago, which would leave me with a lot of work to do), or is there any possible, conceivable way to retrieve the .py file from an already loaded module? I probably deserve this for being so cavalier, but I'm seriously desperate here.

Comment: to retrieve what you typed in the console: `import readline; print '\n'.join([str(readline.get_history_item(i)) for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length())])` but this probably does not solve your problem

Comment: I don't think that is really what he's looking for. He knows the name of the module he loaded, he's looking to retrieve the contents of the currently loaded module.

Comment: If you have a pyc file still hanging around, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file)? (I think ipython produces pyc files, but not sure)

Comment: Slater is right. What I'm worried about is what the executable script that ipython remembers even looks like, and whether whatever format it's in can be re-structured into a simple .py. I know that when I change a .py file's contents, before reloading the module, ipython throws ERRORS from the before-change script, while showing the actual CONTENTS of the after-change script. Which leads me to believe it's not just saving a readable format of the file in the background.

Comment: Given you are in an Ipython session, have you tested `my_module??`... never mind, does not work if the file is gone.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, I have a .pyc but I'm pretty sure it's for the new 0Byte file unfortunatley (it's only 104B). Will rename it and try that method anyway though.

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: Use some utility to fish for strings in the interpreters memory. It's also worth doing this with the disk.

Comment: Very important, but not enough to use source control or backups?

Comment: @Kevin To be fair, it could be a file that's been in progress for a couple of days and has not yet been committed, but the point is still a good one. (And not committing for that long is bad if you can avoid it.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As noted in comments, `inspect.getsource` will not work because it depends on the original file (ie, `module.__file__`).

Best option: check to see if there's a `.pyc` file (ex, `foo.pyc` should be beside `foo.py`). If there is, you can use [Decompile Python 2.7 .pyc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189352/decompile-python-2-7-pyc) to decompile it.

The `inspect` modules also caches the source. You may be able to get lucky and use `inspect.getsource(module)`, or `inspect.getsourcelines(module.function)` if it has been called in the past.

Otherwise you'll need to rebuild the module "manually" by inspecting the exports (ie, `module.__globals__`). Constants and whatnot are obvious, and for functions you can use `func.func_name` to get its name, `func.__doc__` to get the docstring, `inspect.getargspec(func)` to get the arguments, and `func.func_code` to get details about the code: `co_firstlineno` will get the line number, then `co_code` will get the code. There's more on decompiling that here: [Exploring and decompiling python bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149513/exploring-and-decompiling-python-bytecode)

For example, to use `uncompyle2`:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print "Hello, world!"
...
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> import uncompyle2
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> uncompyle2.uncompyle("2.7", foo.func_code, out=out)
>>> print out.getvalue()
print 'Hello, world!'
```

But, no — I'm not aware of any more straight forward method to take a module and get the source code back out.

Comment: You left out the last 2 steps: start using source control and never be susceptible to this mistake again!

Comment: pfft, but how would I get all these sweet sweet internet points if people went and did silly things like that?

Comment: To be clear, isn't your link only for decompiling .pyc files? Or is uncompyle2 capable of interpreting module.function.func_code.co_code, or maybe dis.dis(module.function)?

Comment: @LukeDavis uncompyle can handle `func_code`. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

With the process still running, you can look to your namespace to find candidates to restore:

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'readline', 'rlcompleter', 'test']
```

Let's peek at what we have in store for `test`:

```
>>> help(test)

Help on module test:

NAME
    test

FILE
    /Users/tfisher/code/ffi4wd/test.py

FUNCTIONS
    call_cat(cat)

DATA
    cat_name = 'commander sprinkles'
```

Which has cleaner output than looking at the locals inside of `test`:

```
>>> dir(test)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'call_cat', 'cat_name', 'json']
```

Using the [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code), we can get the argument specifications for functions:

```
>>> inspect.getargspec(test.call_cat)
ArgSpec(args=['cat'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

or the lines inside our functions:

```
>>> inspect.getsourcelines(test.call_cat)
(['def call_cat(cat):\n', '    print("Hello %s" % cat)\n'], 5)
```

Which is reasonably close to the original:

```
import json

cat_name = 'commander sprinkles'

def call_cat(cat):
    print("Hello %s" % cat)
```

Which should work if the file gets deleted after being imported and hasn't been replaced by a file of the same name that's newer (`getsourcelines` uses the object cache if possible):

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.10

$ ls | grep test
$
```

Comment: `inspect.getsourcelines` will not work; see comments on Ryan's answer.

Comment: @DavidWolever are you sure? `getsourcelines` is working on my machine with the file missing.  Its mechanism may work differently than `getsource`.

Comment: Emphatically: http://hul.wolever.net/skitch/inspect-get-source-lines-20150729-141243.png

Comment: Also, `inspect` does cache the source. Try it again from a fresh session (ie, import the module, delete/truncate the file, then try to getsource).

Comment: I saw your edit re: `getsourcelines`.  I'm leaving my answer in place as it may work for OP -- swapping out the contents of the file means re-triggering the import because the file is newer; not necessarily the case.  edit: Your comment came in as I hit enter: Yeah -- I saw the cache in the source for 2.7.10.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use `inspect`

import `inspect` in your Ipython session, and, assuming you are trying to recover `myModule`, do:

`q = inspect.getsource(myModule)`

and write `q` to a file.

[Edit]
 This worked for me simulating the problem using Python 2.7.6, IPython 1.2.1

[Edit #2]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if the file has been deleted (just tested).

Comment: This won't work. `inspect.getsource` reads from `module.__file__`, which will be zero'd.

Comment: Figure out what versions of Python it works for and which it doesn't and you can probably get the downvotes reversed by noting it in your answer.

Comment: I've tested this using both 2 and 3 and cannot get it to work so I'm afraid my downvote will be staying.

Comment: Well now I just want to know how/why this works for Ryan!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the session? Because this _shouldn't_ work (based on my reading of the source): http://hul.wolever.net/skitch/inspect-get-source-lines-20150729-141243.png

Comment: There may be a difference between deleting the source file and truncating it.

Comment: Ah yes true. I deleted the source file.

Comment: Also, `inspect` does cache the source. Try it again from a fresh session (ie, import the module, delete/truncate the file, then try to getsource).

Comment: @DavidWolever I think this caching point is what made me think my tested version worked; see line 9 of edit 2. My apologies for the confusion