# Converting python byte code to regular python code

Tags: python

How do I convert the following byte code to normal python code? I got this code by decompiling a pyc file. Some of the code was decompiled to its original code but the majority did not. Any idea how I can get this byte code to its source code?

```
L. 174       396  BUILD_LIST_0          0
             398  STORE_FAST               'javascripts'

L. 177       400  SETUP_LOOP          490  'to 490'
             402  LOAD_GLOBAL              range
             404  LOAD_CONST               0
             406  LOAD_GLOBAL              len
             408  LOAD_FAST                'incident_tags'
             410  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  '1 positional argument'
             412  CALL_FUNCTION_2       2  '2 positional arguments'
             414  GET_ITER
             416  FOR_ITER            488  'to 488'
             418  STORE_FAST               'i'

L. 178       420  LOAD_GLOBAL              str
             422  LOAD_FAST                'incident_tags'
             424  LOAD_FAST                'i'
             426  BINARY_SUBSCR
             428  LOAD_ATTR                text
             430  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  '1 positional argument'
             432  LOAD_GLOBAL              list_of_incidents
             434  COMPARE_OP               not-in
         436_438  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   462  'to 462'

L. 179       440  LOAD_FAST                'javascripts'
             442  LOAD_METHOD              append
             444  LOAD_FAST                'incident_tags'
             446  LOAD_FAST                'i'
             448  BINARY_SUBSCR
             450  LOAD_METHOD              get_attribute
             452  LOAD_STR                 'href'
             454  CALL_METHOD_1         1  '1 positional argument'
             456  CALL_METHOD_1         1  '1 positional argument'
             458  POP_TOP
             460  JUMP_BACK           416  'to 416'
           462_0  COME_FROM           436  '436'

L. 181       462  LOAD_GLOBAL              print
             464  LOAD_STR                 'Ignore '
             466  LOAD_FAST                'incident_tags'
             468  LOAD_FAST                'i'
             470  BINARY_SUBSCR
             472  LOAD_ATTR                text
             474  BINARY_ADD
             476  LOAD_STR                 '. It is already completed.'
             478  BINARY_ADD
             480  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  '1 positional argument'
             482  POP_TOP
         484_486  JUMP_BACK           416  'to 416'
             488  POP_BLOCK
           490_0  COME_FROM_LOOP      400  '400'

L. 184   490_492  SETUP_LOOP         3694  'to 3694'
             494  LOAD_GLOBAL              range
             496  LOAD_CONST               0
             498  LOAD_GLOBAL              len
             500  LOAD_FAST                'javascripts'
             502  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  '1 positional argument'
             504  CALL_FUNCTION_2       2  '2 positional arguments'
             506  GET_ITER
           508_0  COME_FROM           636  '636'
         508_510  FOR_ITER           3692  'to 3692'
             512  STORE_FAST               'i'

L. 187       514  LOAD_FAST                'self'
             516  LOAD_ATTR                driver
             518  LOAD_METHOD              execute_script
             520  LOAD_FAST                'javascripts'
             522  LOAD_FAST                'i'
             524  BINARY_SUBSCR
             526  CALL_METHOD_1         1  '1 positional argument'
             528  POP_TOP

L. 189       530  LOAD_GLOBAL              time
             532  LOAD_METHOD              sleep
             534  LOAD_CONST               1
             536  CALL_METHOD_1         1  '1 positional argument'
             538  POP_TOP
```

Comment: It's not something available in standard Python, and I'm not aware of any 3rd-party tools that do this kind of conversion.

Comment: Some potential tools are listed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149513/what-tools-or-libraries-are-there-for-decompiling-python-and-exploring-bytecode

Comment: This wouldn't be trivial, there's not just some built-in function that will do this. You'd be better off googling for projects that already exist. Of course, this is going to be *very* version dependent.

Comment: This **amount** of bytecode is trivial to decompile by hand.  Are you really asking about some larger, unspecified body of code?

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes. I just showed a snippet of the data

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `uncompyle6` module. (You need the raw `.pyc`  or `.pyo` file though). To install, run

```sh
~$ pip install uncompyle6
```

Then, to decompile any Python bytecode file, run

```sh
~$ uncompyle6 path/to/bytecode/file.pyc
```

For an overview of all available options, run

```sh
~$ uncompyle6 -h
```

It supports all Python versions from 2.4 to 3.8. You can find the project' homepage at https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using by importing the dis module and using the dir() method to get the **code** of each function, further used the dir() to get the co_code and finally using dis function to get the bytecodes.  The process is really tedious but it gave me the results I was looking for.

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

dir(add) 
#This displays all attributes available to the add function. There are tons of them but I'm only interested in the __code__
my_object = add.__code__  
dir(my_object)
#this displays a list of available attributes to the code object (my_object) but 
I'm only interested in the co_code attribute
code = my_object.co_code
list(code) #convert the co_code object to list.  This displays the bytecode but to #view it in human readable form use dis.opname
import dis
dir(dis) # to view all available attributes.  I'm interested in a only few of them
dis.opname() #supply the bytecode value.
```

The process is actually tedious but can be automated if you understand the concept.